# What type of analysis to do for Dissertation- EMOTION RECOGNITION

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, post-hoc, ancova, manova

In my study, participants take part in the State Trait Anxiety Inventory (STAI) where they are ranked into high or low trait anxiety groups.
Participants are then shown multiple videos of 7 different emotions.

IV- High or low trait anxiety group
DV- Correct responses of emotion.

The measurement of 'correct responses of emotion' is a number of how many correct responses for each emotion the participants scored. For example Happy-7 Sad-4 Angry- 3 Fear- 8 etc.

I want to see if there are significant differences in the general emotion ability with regard to participants with low levels of trait anxiety and if there are any differences in the recognition of specific emotions. For example the literature has found that participants with high levels of trait anxiety are more accurate in recognition of fear.

I am unsure about analysing the data, I am thinking of doing a repeated measures ANOVA, but I don't know if that is the correct analysis to do.

Any help is very much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What would be the objective of your analysis?  What other observations are you making that might be involved in an ANOVA?

Comment: I want to see if there are significant differences in the general emotion ability with regard to participants with low levels of trait anxiety and if there are any differences in the recognition of specific emotions.                                                                             For example the literature has found that participants with high levels of trait anxiety are more accurate in recognition of fear.

Comment: Thank you.  Could you explain what kind of measurement "correct responses of emotion" might be?

Comment: The measurement of 'correct responses of emotion' is a number of how many correct responses for each emotion the participants scored. For example Happy-7 Sad-4 Angry- 3 Fear- 8 etc.